# Cucumber I should see all of the texts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

I need to use:

in Feature file

```
Then I should see all of the texts:
  | the first text  |
  | the third text  |
  | the fourth text |
```

Help, please, describe this step:

in step file

```
Then(/^I should see all text:$/) do |table|
  # table is a Cucumber::Ast::Table
  ........................
end
```

========================================================================

I decided that follows:

```
Then(/^I should see all text:$/) do |table|
  table.rows.flatten.each do |text|
    should have_content(text)
  end
end
```

but
if you have better step, please write!

Thanks!

Comment: Try passing `--expand` when you run scenarios. It should print them out?

Comment: In step file: `@texts = table.raw` and you will get in `@texts` an array of strings from your table

Comment: With --expand same result!

Comment: Is there still a question or was the edit an answer to your own question?